# screen size mismatch causing screenshot comparisons to fail

Tags: resize, comparison, screenshot, playwright

i have about 100 pages to verify with screenshots. When i update the baseline, and then compare pages with the baseline, about 60% of them are failures due to mismatched sizes - "Expected an image 1366px by 783px, received 1349 by 783px. 3242 pixels (ratio 0.01 of all image pixels) are different".  These expected and received are different for different pages.

I have tried explicitly setting the viewport size in the config and in the test. Still get slight differences.  I tried setting the viewport to null, and removing devices in the config - same result.
If i set the viewport to something large, why would it fail for some pages and not others?  How do I force the baseline snapshot to be the same size as the test snapshot?  Does each page have to have its own custom "expected" size?  Does it matter where the cursor is during the (headed) test?

here's some code...

```js
test('Compare', async({page})=>{
await page.goto(url);
await expect.soft(page).toHaveScreenshot('url.png',{fullPage:true,mask:[page.locator('tbody'),page.getByTitle(/...ResetPassword.../),page.getByLabel('Label1'),page.getByText(/Version[0-9]/)]});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That difference of 17 pixels is almost certainly due to a browser scrollbar being either present or absent. I have also seen very unpredictable behaviour on some tests, which makes the screenshot feature difficult to rely on.

Some things to try:

- Always run the tests headless
- Run the tests in different browsers to see if some give more predictable results. I have definitely had problems in Chromium.
- Only screenshot a page element rather than the full page (i.e. locator.screenshot rather than page.screenshot).
- Set {animations: 'disabled'} in case something is moving on the page causing it to change size.
- Set the mouse pointer to a fixed location with page.mouse.move(0, 0)
- Although widely discouraged, in Chromium introducing a deliberate wait with waitForTimeout(5000) seemed to make the result more stable.

Of those I think frustratingly the 5s delay had the most impact.

Comment: Headless really helps; but, how would I just hide the problem elements - the table or the tbody,th, etc before the snapshot?  I read where you could put your focus on an element, but not how to focus on everything except one or two elements.

Comment: And the mask sizes are different.  Who cares?

Comment: Even stranger. If i set viewport size 1920x1200, (wait for timeout 3 seconds), animations disabled, running headless (from terminal ps) fails as described above, but running headed (from test runner) passes.  I am so confused!

Comment: Did you update your screenshot in headless mode? I didn't find 3s to be long enough to become stable, but it's hard to be certain when the behaviour is so inconsistent.

Comment: I notice that in the latest version, v1.41, Playwright allows you to define custom css when calling any of the screenshot methods. You could try using that to hide problematic elements and possibly force-hide scrollbars with 'overflow: hidden'

Comment: update to 1.41 helps. Thanks!